# How can I localize an UIBarButtonItem ? xcode

Tags: ios, localization, uibarbuttonitem

When localizing an image, I use this code:

```
 UIImage* localTutorial = [UIImage imageNamed:NSLocalizedString(@"tutorial.png", nil)];
```

I want to localize a UIBarButtonItem and change it's title according to localized strings, how can I make this happen. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start by reading the "Introduction to Internationalization Programming Topics" document in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong, the method to be used in the following way

```
 NSString *barButtonItemTitle = NSLocalizedString(@"Button title here", @"")
 UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:barButtonItemTitle
            style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image style:(UIBarButtonItemStyle)style target:(id)target action:(SEL)action
```

or

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title style:(UIBarButtonItemStyle)style target:(id)target action:(SEL)action
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift:**

```
// MARK: - Lifecycle Methods
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // if it's the back button
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: NSLocalizedString("action_close", comment: ""), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.didTapMyLocalizedBarButtonItem))

    // OR maybe you need the following instead (like I did):

    // if this is the root view controller for the current navigation controller (therefore, it's not a back button technically)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: NSLocalizedString("action_close", comment: ""), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.didTapMyLocalizedBarButtonItem))
}

// MARK: - Custom Button Action
@IBAction func didTapMyLocalizedBarButtonItem(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Custom bar button item tapped.")
}
```